# How to compute $\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{(4n^2+8n+3)2^n}{n!}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

How to compute $\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{(4n^2+8n+3)2^n}{n!}$?

I am trying to connect the series to $e^x$

My try: $\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{(4n^2+8n+3)2^n}{n!}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{(2n+1)(2n+3)2^n}{n!}$

Let $x=\sqrt{2}$, then the series becomes $\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{(2n+1)(2n+3)x^{2n}}{n!}$.

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{(2n+1)(2n+3)x^{2n}}{n!}=\frac{d}{dx}\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{(2n+3)x^{2n+1}}{n!}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{(2n+3)x^{2n+2}}{n!}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{x^{2n+3}}{n!}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}x^3\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{(x^{2})^n}{n!}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}x^3e^{x^{2}}$

In the end we subtract $\sum^{1}_{n=0}\frac{(4n^2+8n+3)2^n}{n!}$ since above we assumed $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}$

Comment: Your approach looks ok, though I haven't checked till the very end.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Let $f(x)=e^x-(1+x)$.   Then, note that

$$f(x)=e^x-(1+x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n }{n!}$$

$$xf'(x)=x(e^x-1)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n\,x^{n} }{n!}$$

$$x(xf'(x))'=x(x+1)e^x-x=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2\,x^{n} }{n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $P(n)$ is a polynomial and you know the series $\sum a_kx^k=f(x)$, then the series $\sum P(k)a_kx^k =P(xD)f(x)$ where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ denotes the differential operator.

Here $f=e^x$, which eventually you need to evaluate when $x=2$.

Comment: Just edited the solution, Is it correct now?